# wcf host address issue

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a project where i need two endpoints and for both the endpoints i have base address as below

```
<host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress ="http://localhost:62239/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
```

My service is hosted at IIS express 
http://localhost:77888

Now I am browsing my service with the help of "http://localhost:62239/" it is showing 400 bad request.

Please let me know why is it unable to browse at port 62239 and if services is already hosted at iis express whether we need to specify host address in config or not ?

As i know use of base address but not sure what should happen in this specific case.

Thank you

Comment: BaseAddress is ignored in IIS - the base address will be the location of the .svc file.

Comment: but what will happen if i add base address as  "https://localhost.62239" use https instead of http will it also ignore if binding as wshttpbinding and SSL enabled for it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put in as base address - IIS will ignore it.  You can set an explicit endpoint in the config, however, which could state the port and the binding.

Comment: So what is happening in this case when i use https port 62239 i am able to access my service with cross marked on https which means may be secure connection as SSL enabled here . That is the reason i came across this question.

Comment: @Akhilesh describe your real question clearly.